MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to MongoDB Atlas from Express Server
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const dotenv = require("dotenv").config();

const authRoutes = require("./routes/auth");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json()); 
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 
app.use(express.static("public")); 

// mongoose
mongoose
  .connect(
    "mongodb+srv://<username:password>@cluster1.1h79s.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=Cluster1"
  )
  .then(() => {
    console.log("MongoDB cennect");
    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server Port: ${PORT}`));
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(`${err} did not connect`));

when I try to start my Express server, I get the following error:
MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist.

Any help or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!
I'm currently facing an issue while trying to connect my Express server to MongoDB Atlas. I have verified the following:

Connection URI: I am using the correct connection string. I replaced username and password with my actual credentials.

IP Whitelisting: I have whitelisted both my local IP address and 0.0.0.0/0 on the MongoDB Atlas security settings.

MongoDB Compass: I can connect to the MongoDB Atlas cluster without any issues using MongoDB Compass.



I also had the same issue and I solved the above issue by using mongoose version 5.13.22 instead of the new version
